# How to plot points that were recorded as meters of distance (X and Y) from a benchmark into a map?

Tags: coordinate-system, import, benchmark

How can I put the 2 points from the table below into a map?

[image]

The "lat" and "lon" are the coordinates of a reference point (location of the RTK base station), these two columns are constant for all the points. The columns "x2" and "y3" has the actual location of each point. They are in meters of distance from the reference point in each axis.

So the 1st point is 106 m East and 381 m South of the reference point.

How do I plot these points into a map?

Accuracy is important in this case and yes, I have hundreds of thousands of points to calculate, I just used two here to simplify the question.

I tried to convert the distances that I have in meters now to decimal degrees and then sum with the reference point coordinates but wasn't able to get the locations accurate enough.

Comment: Specifying two software stacks makes this two questions (violating the One question per Question poly). Choose one stack, attempt to complete the task, then edit the question to reflect a problem if you encounter one.

Comment: Thanks Vince but I'm asking either one or the other and not for both of them.

Comment: It's all about the answers here. Two very different correct answers means it's two questions. There are other flaws, like not making an attempt to solve the task in either environment. Even the task of "plotting" is unclear.

Comment: You still have two stacks tagged, and the Question *doesn't demonstrate an attempt to solve the task*. The [Tour] states that you should `Include details about what you have tried...`. If you choose a GIS tool and have difficulty, you have the beginnings of a question (the rest is to document what you attempted, and what the error was). Right now the question can be closed as too broad, unclear, and missing a code attempt (might be a duplicate as well -- look under the tag [geodesy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodesy)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your reference lat/lon to a projected coordinate system that uses easting and northing in meters, something like UTM. You can then directly add the offsets to the base point to get coordinates of the new points. The coords in your example lie on the boundary between zones 15 and 16. If your x offsets are mostly positive, then use zone 16.
In that case, your easting is 263553.97, your northing is 4987329.50 WGS84 datum.

Comment: Simple and spot on, it did the trick!